# Facebook isn't crawling my site

Tags: facebook, user-agent, bots, web-crawler

When I publish link of my site to facebook, it's now showing thumbnails and it's showing my old site's titles. I just added opengraph code to my site, but that don't help. When I check my site in facebook debug, it shows Response code: 403. I guess this means that my site is blocking facebook bots, but I don't see how is this possible. Since recently everything worked fine. If this is the case, can you tell me how to unblock it...

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fracunovodstvo.com.ba

Comment: Contact your hosting provider

Comment: I contacted them already, they say everything fine on the server :S

Comment: Do you see any request being done in the log from Facebook when you use the open graph debugger?

Comment: yes, i can see in user-agent log, that facebook agent facebookexternalhit/1.1 is active...

Comment: from the log, 66.220.147.246 - - [31/Dec/2011:15:23:58 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 4244 "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some digging and and it seams as Facebook actually get a 403 response. Here is what i did:

```
$ nc -l -p 8000 > fbbot-request
listening on [any] 8000 ...
```

Run the debugger on `http://mydebughost:8000` and I get:

```
connect to [78.108.54.9] from out-fc245.tfbnw.net [66.220.153.245] 48731
$ cat fbbot-request 
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
Host: mydebughost:8000
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Range: bytes=0-40960
Connection: close
```

Now change the `Host` header to `racunovodstvo.com.ba` and do the request:

```
$ cat fbbot-request | nc racunovodstvo.com.ba 80 | head
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Sat, 31 Dec 2011 14:29:48 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Mon, 02 May 2011 07:52:14 GMT
ETag: "444007-1094-4dbe62ae"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 4244
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

And after some more digging it seams as the web server get confused by the `Range: bytes=0-40960` header.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies. Do you have any idea what can I do to resolve this. This is bugging me for two days and still nothing..

Comment: Seams weird if this is problem with Apache, i guess something goes wrong in php etc.

Comment: Site is in wordpress, i deactivated all plugins, because I read that can be an issue, but nothing )=

Comment: Seams to happen even for static files like images, maybe some at your hosting company has configured the Apache a bit to tight? There was a [Apache security problem involving the range header](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-announce/201108.mbox/%3C20110826103531.998348F82@minotaur.apache.org%3E) not so long ago.

Comment: I called them again, they say everythings ok. I think also that it's apache thing. So I will have to change the hosting. Can see anything else to resolve this problem. Thanks mate for your effort

Comment: Okok, your welcome. Let me know if you figure it out.

Comment: Still nothing, bugger =)