# Problems with Facebook OpenGraph and Wordpress

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-opengraph

I installed some meta tags in my wordpress blog (header file), example:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="340807095947367" /> 
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Website" />  
<meta property="og:description" content="Description HERE" />  
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />  
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mywebsite.com/img/tinypic.png" />
```

And this are working fine with all wordpress posts and pages but it fails with home (main page). Seems that Facebook can't find these meta tags in my home, but they are in source code.

I really don't know what is causing this error, so i can't fix it.

Comment: Have you tried clearing facebook's cache of the page, by running the site through their debugger? http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Yes, but i get always the same error in main page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [facebook open graph debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.portodemosonline.com%2F) the home URL seams to return 503 bad response most of the times, but occationlly 200 OK. If you want a handy way to "emulate" the Facebook fetch bot yourself and fiddle around check out [Facebook isn't crawling my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688461/facebook-isnt-crawling-my-site/8688659)

The warning about "Inferred Property" is because your home URL does not explicitly provide `og:url` and `og:title` tags. Add something like this to the home URL document:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Porto de Mós Online - O Portal do seu Concelho" />  
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.portodemosonline.com/" />
```

Also the home URL seams to have some kind of broken BOM header (`0x09 0xef 0xbb 0xbf`) before the doctype that might confuse. `0x09` is tab so i would suspect that some PHP file is outputting this somehow, maybe a junk tab outside the `<?php ?>` tags.

Comment: But even it returns 200 i get the same message: `
Inferred Property: The og:url property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property: The og:title property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.`

Comment: Same error... I realize that only works with posts.. Not single pages or home. And if you see the source code, meta tags are there.

Comment: I found some strange characters before "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC (...)" in header.php (in my template folder) and deleted it.. Now it's working! Big thanks! :) Just one more question: I'm editing php files with notepad++, so how can i prevent this situations in future?

Comment: Have no idea, i dont use notepad++ myself. But i would guess that the problem was the tab character.

Answer (score 1):

To the point above, I wanted to add a little specificity. At the top of the  tags in the header.php file, (wordpress) my template file ALSO had ?>. I removed the "!DOCTYPE" and all is indeed well.

I would hat for someone to use a plugin who doesn't need to and can still get all the benefits of the XFBML/HTML5 attributes this code can offer.

Thanks for staying with it and posting this. I know it's not a discussion, but there's a little detail in there. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that rather than adding custom open graph parameters, try to use this plugin: 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-facebook-open-graph-protocol/

This plugin is well and works fine. I am using this for my blog.

Comment: I already tried multiple plugins. I have this page [link](http://www.algarveferias.net/) in same server account and same plugins and is fine.. I really don't understand why this [link](http://www.portodemosonline.com/) aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

Problems like this are the reason I wrote a plugin to handle it -- Complete Open Graph. I've tried other plugins past, and found them to make some strange assumptions about content I want to use for Open Graph, or just be waaaaaay too much code bloat for what I want to use it for. I think mine is the perfect balance of works-out-of-the-box, and yet flexible enough for developers to filter as they need. You should check it out!

https://wordpress.org/plugins/complete-open-graph/